# Problem with communication on RS232

Tags: 12.04, serial-port

I have used serial device using RS232 communication.
I want to check signal of device.
When I push its button, I can get Hexa data (After I will say signal).
My computer has 4 serial ports (main board: asrock IMB-183), so I want to connect serial to device.
When I test the device using USB2SERIAL, I can get the signal with minicom.
But when I use serial port, minicom does not work.

I checked the Rx, Tx using Windows (same computer and same device) with serial
at terminal program (like highper terminal), I can get the signal. 
So I think I have problem with Linux together with using serial port.

I checked my BIOS. At SuperI/O I turned on COM port to enable.
and I checked group, dialout.

Now I show you status of my computer and device.

```
 # id
......, 20(dialout), .......

 # cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo : 1.0 driver revision:
0: uart : 16550A port : 000003F8 irq: 4 tx:0 rx:0 RTS|DTR
1: uart : 16550A port : 000002F8 irq: 3 tx:0 rx:0 RTS|DTR
........
```

linux 3.13.0-32-generic,
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you try to catch the device output by using `cat /dev/ttyS0` command? The number here is the port number, test it from 0 - 3 if you have 4 ports.

Comment: I check all port to cat/dev/ttyS*, but all port do show anything else.

Comment: Try `screen /dev/ttyS0`, you can find more instructions here: [Working with the serial console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/working_with_the_serial_console), I would say it's better to check if the serial port works on your system, search "RS-232 loopback". Or if you happen to have a COM-to-COM connector, connect it with another system that has a working serial port and test some simple TX/RX with `echo` / `screen` command on them.

Comment: to P.-H. Lin, I checked all hardware included RS-232 loopback at windows.
all of port is ok. but when i boot with ubuntu, Serial port dosen't work.
But!!!! now I found something that ttyS0 is work. and check echo / cat command is ok. but others not work.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that all ports work on Windows but not Ubuntu, maybe you can try to use a newer kernel (A 16.04 / 16.10 LiveUSB will do) to see if it can make other ports work.

Anyway, at least it seems that your ttyS0 is working with echo / cat command. The last thing I can suggest is that if you still can't get any signal from you serial device, try to use `stty` command to change the baud rate:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0  # Print current setting
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600  # Set the baud rate
```

9600 here should be replaced with the correct baud rate.

More information about stty command can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty).